# Snowflake stored procedure bind arguments issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is my sample code below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE database.schema.sp_sample(dynamic_columns VARCHAR, dynamic_where_clause VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
$$
rs="Success";
try {
retrieve_queries_sql = `SELECT COL_1, COL_2, ? FROM table ? GROUP BY ?`;
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: retrieve_queries_sql, binds:[DYNAMIC_COLUMNS, DYNAMIC_WHERE_CLAUSE, DYNAMIC_COLUMNS]} );
var rs = stmt.execute();
}
catch(err) {
rs= "Failed Message: "+err.message;
}
return rs;
$$;
```

When I try to bind these columns Snowflake throws an error Unexpected ? and I even tried using :1, :2 even that didnt work same error Unexpected :

Dont want to prefer interpolation ${dynamic_columns} or ${dynamic_where_clause} as it can lead to sql injection concerns

How to bind the arguments in the best possible way? Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in other UDF the parameters to the JavaScript function need to be ALL_CAPS in the JavaScript body, as the SQL part (the function declaration) the SQL is case insensitive, while java it's "how it really is" which is upper case. Or you can double quote then in the declaration, as lower case, to have then lower case in the body.

Comment: i am using the uppercase inside the stored procedure same error.
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: retrieve_queries_sql, binds:[DYNAMIC_COLUMNS, DYNAMIC_WHERE_CLAUSE, DYNAMIC_COLUMNS]} );